# No module named yum when working on RHEL 8

Tags: python, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm, pip

Since our application works with `python2`, we needed to move to RHEL 8

After we installed `python2` on RHEL 8 machine, we see the following:

```
rpm -qa | grep python2
python2-pip-9.0.3-19.module+el8.6.0+13001+ad200bd9.noarch
python2-setuptools-wheel-39.0.1-13.module+el8.4.0+9442+27d0e81c.noarch
python2-pip-wheel-9.0.3-19.module+el8.6.0+13001+ad200bd9.noarch
python2-2.7.18-11.module+el8.7.0+15681+7a92afba.x86_64
python2-libs-2.7.18-11.module+el8.7.0+15681+7a92afba.x86_64
python2-setuptools-39.0.1-13.module+el8.4.0+9442+27d0e81c.noarch
```

but when we try to use `import yum`, we then get an error about 'No module named yum' with the following output:

```
python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Jun 17 2022, 07:56:00)
[GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-13)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yum
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yum
```

The installed rpm for yum are:

```
rpm -qa | grep yum
yum-4.4.2-11.el8.noarch
yum-utils-4.0.18-4.el8.noarch
```

and yum appears as:

```
more /usr/bin/yum
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
try:
    import yum
except ImportError:
    print >> sys.stderr, """\
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   %s

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
%s

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

""" % (sys.exc_value, sys.version)
    sys.exit(1)

sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/yum-cli')
try:
    import yummain
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
    print >> sys.stderr, "\n\nExiting on user cancel."
    sys.exit(1)
```

and from `pip2` list we get this output:

```
pip2 list
pip (9.0.3)
setuptools (39.0.1)
```

So why are we getting the error about  `No module named yum`?

https://www.getpagespeed.com/solutions/python-scripts-running-on-rocky-linux-8-can-not-import-yum

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4289441

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at a [StackO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632016/yum-no-module-named-yum) a simple fix might be making a change in `/usr/bin/yum`. Change the first line `!#/usr/bin/python` to `!#/usr/bin/python2.7`

There is also a more recent, but more complex [RHEL customer portal solution](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21199) from April 25, 2023.

**Resolutions**

> There are multiple possible causes for this issue. Usually this issue
> is a result of the python path being incorrectly set. The python path
> sys.path is dynamically built during python initialization using
> several methods, so depending on the system in question the fix may be
> one of the following:

**Resolution 1**

> Unset the PYTHONHOME variable:
>
> `# unset PYTHONHOME`

> For permanent change remove entry from root's .bashrc or .bash_profile if present.
>
> Reinstall python package by running following command:
>
> `# rpm -Uvh --replacefiles --replacepkgs python-<version>.rpm`

**Resolution 2**

> If there is no PYTHONHOME variable set, check to ensure there is no
> third-party python located underneath the improper /lib/ location
> instead of /lib64/. Check the python path as well as ldd to see which
> files are being loaded:

```
 # python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)" ['',
 '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
 
 # ldd /usr/bin/python
     linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd46b3b000)
     libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007efe38aaf000)  <-----take note of this file location
     libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007efe38893000)
     libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007efe3868f000)
     libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007efe3848c000)
     libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007efe3818a000)
     libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007efe37dbc000)
     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007efe38e7b000)
```

> The above output indicates what is expected. If you see
> /usr/lib/python2.7 being loaded instead of /usr/lib64/python2.7 you
> should check the following:
>
> `# ls -l /lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0`
>
> `# rpm -qf /lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0`

> If you find that there is a file at
> /lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 and it is not owned by any package, you
> should move that file aside and see if the issue remains:
>
> `# mv /lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /tmp/`
>
> The prioritized python can also
> be in /root/.local, thus please ensure that there is no python under
> this path.

**Root Cause(s)**

- PYTHONHOME variable was set as environment variable on system.
- Python libraries/files are modified which can be observed from output
  of rpm -Va command.
- Third party python modules are installed on system which found in
  output of ldd /usr/bin/python command.
- The package rpm-python* is not installed.
- There is a third-party /lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 that is being loaded
  instead of the proper system location of /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0.
  This causes the python module search path defined by sys.path to be
  incorrectly set, resulting in the system not finding the installed
  python modules

Comment: in /usr/bin/yum , we have the first line as #!/usr/libexec/platform-python , so its not as "!#/usr/bin/python" , what we can do about this?

Comment: @KingDavid darn, go figure it’s slightly different for the presumable easy fix. You could try updating it to what I posted. You could also try tacking on 2.7 it python-platform, but I don’t know if that is valid or not. Did you attempt the other more involved resolutions? I’ll see if I can find anything regarding /usr/libexec/python-platform